# How can I make use of top level ActorSystem everywhere needed?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to learn `akka-http` and working on their [example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/client-side/request-level.html)

Here is what my code looks like

```
  val system = ActorSystem.create("enterpriseSystem", ConfigFactory.load("application"))
  val notifier = system.actorOf(Props[Notifier], "notifier")
```

and Notifier as

```
class Notifier extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def receive = {
    case CommunicateECFailure =>
      log.info("notifying about EC Failure")
      val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
        Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = "http://localhost:8080"))

      responseFuture onComplete {
        case response =>
          log.info("response received {}", response)
          log.info("notified about EC Failure")
      }
  }
```

As you can see I create new `ActorSystem` with every `Actor` creation, is that bad? I read in akka docs that you should not have many ActorSystems

How can I avoid that? passing it as an argument during construction?

Answer (score 5):

You are definitely wrong in creating new `ActorSystem` every time! `ActorSystem` is available in each actor `context`:

```
context.system
```